# CSS Width not working but max and min width does

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css

I have a side navigation with a header and a middle section. EG

```
<div>
    <aside></aside>
    <div>
        <header></header>
        <div class="middle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My aside has a fixed width on EG `300px` but on certain screens, the width is being ignored.
The header and middle grow using flex to 100% width and the header has a fixed hight of 60px.

First one I found was `display: table`, anything with this on cause the navigation to be smaller and squashed all the nav items. I fixed this because I dont actually need the `display: table` (flexbox works fine)

The second issue which I cannot figure out is when using `pre`. Why does the pre break the navigation width? I can fix this by changing the navigation to the follow but I dont understand why.

```
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
width: 100%;
```

Does anyone know why and is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

PS I have bootstrap and tailwind applied which maybe causing issues. Tailwind classes are prefixed as to not clash with bootstrap

Comment: Adding `min-width: 100%; width: 0;` to the pre fixes this. But I still dont know why. :-)

Comment: Please put your code in a demo snippet using the editor so we can see the problem.